# Check the convergence (& absolutely) of parametric integral

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

$$\int\limits_{-1}^{1} \left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)^{\alpha} \ln(2+x)dx$$

Don't know where to start..

Comment: It may help do do the substitution $y=(1+x)/(1-x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $$ f(x):=\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)^{\alpha} \ln(2+x), \quad x \in (-1,1).$$ This function is continuous on $(-1,1)$, let's see what happens near $-1$ and near $1$.

- Near $x=-1$.

$$
f(x) \sim_{-1} \frac{1}{2^{\alpha}}(1+x)^{\alpha+1} 
$$
where we have used $\ln (1+u) \sim_0 u$, then the integral of $\displaystyle (1+x)^{\alpha+1} $ is convergent near $x=-1$ if and only if $\alpha >-2. $

- Near $x=1$.

$$
f(x) \sim_{1}  \frac{2^{\alpha}\ln 3}{(1-x)^{\alpha}}
$$
and the integral of $\displaystyle \frac{1}{(1-x)^{\alpha}} $ is convergent near $x=1$ if and only if $\alpha <1. $

Consequently, your integral is convergent for all real numbers such that $ -2<\alpha <1.$

Comment: Olivier, thank you so much, it seems like correct :) And, while the $f(x) > 0$ in this range, would it be absolutly converging with the same $\alpha$ ?

Comment: @Alej You are welcome. If I'm not mistaken we have $f(x)>0$ for $-1<x<1.$ No? So the absolute convergence is ensured. Thanks.